# How to find last/first not empty child using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

Let's say I have this:

```
<div>
   <span>1</span>
   <span>2</span>
   <span>3</span>
   <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

and want to add comma to each non-empty element, besides the last non-empty one (Not last child). So from "1 2 3" I want to have "1, 2, 3".

Excluding last child is easy
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qo1swwx/)
But this last non-empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've found the solution that works every time and in every possible case here: https://jsfiddle.net/4ktq3d3u/1 :)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span></span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span></span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span><span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
span:not(:first-child):not(:empty)::before {
    content: ', ';
}

span:empty + span:not(:empty)::before {
    content: '';
}

span:not(:empty) ~ span:empty + span:not(:empty)::before {
    content: ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different approach, but it might work for you.  Instead of putting the commas after each non-empty element, put them BEFORE.  Then, it is possible in CSS to catch the first non-empty element to remove that preceding comma.

```
span::before {content: ', ';}
span:empty::before {content:'';}

span:first-child:empty + span:not(:empty)::before {content:'';}
span:first-child:empty + span:empty + span:not(:empty)::before {content:'';}
/* and so on, if you want to catch up to n empty elements in the front */
```

This does add a blank space between elements, so it will look like 1 , 2 , 3 instead of 1, 2, 3.  But, you can solve that by changing the HTML to remove spaces between the spans.  Or other creative CSS methods.

https://jsfiddle.net/37L334hj/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much :)
I tried this approach as well and got this https://jsfiddle.net/vfqoyw45/
Your solution is great, but it won't work if you don't have any empty elements in the beginning, but mine won't work if you have empty elements between non-empty :P 
Gotta combined these two solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use ::after, with your content as the comma ",":

[CSS ::after Selector | w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp)

For your second to last child:

[CSS :nth-last-child() Selector | w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp)

Then exclude last child.

Comment: If you had clicked on the link that is in my post you would have known I did used ::after pseudoclass :) 
It's now always second or third last child. 
The condition is last non-empty. We don't know which one is that.

Comment: Maybe you should have just put all your code in the question

Answer (score 1):

Here we go https://jsfiddle.net/1qo1swwx/12/

```
div span:not(:empty)::after {
    content: ', ';
}

div span:nth-last-child(1):not(:empty):after{
    content: '';
}

div span:nth-last-child(2):not(:empty):after{
    content: '';
}

div span:nth-last-child(3):not(:empty):after{
    content: '';
}

div span:nth-last-child(4):not(:empty):after{
    content: '';
}
```

Keep in mind it only cover limited amount of empty elements on end, in my case max 3 blank span on end, thats only one limitation, if need more just update the rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
span:not(:empty)::before {
    content: "";
}

span::before,
span:not(:empty) ~ span::before {
    content: ", ";
}

span:empty:empty::before {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30799635)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this without using js or jquery, because css don't have access to the content of element.

Comment: If you had clicked on the link that is in my post you would have known I used ::after pseudoclass, so adding content via css is not a problem...
js or jquery xD using jquery is using js, oh man...

Comment: I write this because many people use jquery and don't known native js:-)

Comment: Thats not true, you can do this without js, with limitations, but it possible

Answer (score 0):

one line solution

```
span:not(:empty):not(:last-child)::after{
  content: ', '
}
```